# Java - use variable value to assign type to another variable?

Tags: java, types, casting

Is it possible in Java to use variables value for type?

For example:

```
String s = "String";
```

And then I would create another variable `z`, which could use `s` value for his type. Is it possible to do that? Maybe with reflection or some other technique?

Update:

If it's not possible this way, maybe someone could suggest how to give type to variable, when you get what type it is from xml files attribute? Like

`<tag type="String">MyValue</tag>`

And then I could use `type` attributes value for defining variables type?

Comment: You want to give the value of s to z?
So that z would contain "String"?

Comment: I want to when I create variable z, his type would be defined using variable's s value. Like s z; (just using s value as his type).

Comment: That example you gave, still use which type it needs to have, like String and Integer. 
P.S Also why down vote?

Comment: Suppose it's possible and now you have a variable called `z` with type `String`. What are you going to do with it?

Comment: @Joni use it as a parameter for method input value

Comment: Then you have an additional problem: the method to be called is chosen by the compiler, and if the type of `z` is not known until the program is run it can't call the right method. What are you trying do really?

Comment: @Joni well, I have xml configuration file, which defined variable values and their types as attributes. And I need to use these in different methods, depending on their type. So I suppose I need to make some kind of loop, that would check if for example given value can be Integer, then make it Integer and only then use it for method right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you look for something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "java.lang.String";

    Object o = "Some Value";

    Class<?> type;
    try {
        type = Class.forName(s);
        getValue(type, o);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // class was not found
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static <T> T getValue(Class<T> desiredType, Object o) {
    if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(desiredType)) {
        return desiredType.cast(o);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is something I could use.

Answer (score 0):

I know no language allowing it the way you wrote, and about other ways: you could achieve it with typedef in C or C++, but not in Java. However, you could often extend a class like this:

```
public class myName extends originalClassName {}
```

and then use myName instead of originalClassName. However, you can not do this with String, which is final and therefore can't be inherited after.